# Checking a cookie in a PHP script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies

Hey i still need a little bit of help with the rating system but i have a problem checking if the cookie exist this is

```
<?php

    $rating = new ratings($_POST['widget_id']);


    isset($_POST['fetch']) ? $rating->get_ratings() : $rating->vote();





class ratings {

    var $data_file = './ratings.data.txt';
    private $widget_id;
    private $data = array();


function __construct($wid) {

    $this->widget_id = $wid;

    $all = file_get_contents($this->data_file);

    if($all) {
        $this->data = unserialize($all);
    }
}

public function get_ratings() {
    if($this->data[$this->widget_id]) {
        echo json_encode($this->data[$this->widget_id]);
    }
    else {
        $data['widget_id'] = $this->widget_id;
        $data['number_votes'] = 0;
        $data['total_points'] = 0;
        $data['dec_avg'] = 0;
        $data['whole_avg'] = 0;
        echo json_encode($data);
    } 
}
public function vote() {

    # Get the value of the vote
    preg_match('/star_([1-5]{1})/', $_POST['clicked_on'], $match);
    $vote = $match[1];

    $ID = $this->widget_id;
    # Update the record if it exists

    # doesn't update if it already exists
    if (!isset($_COOKIE[$id])) {

    if($this->data[$ID]) {
        $this->data[$ID]['number_votes'] += 1;
        $this->data[$ID]['total_points'] += $vote;
    }
    # Create a new one if it doesn't
    else {
        $this->data[$ID]['number_votes'] = 1;
        $this->data[$ID]['total_points'] = $vote;
    }

    $this->data[$ID]['dec_avg'] = round( $this->data[$ID]['total_points'] / $this->data[$ID]['number_votes'], 1 );
    $this->data[$ID]['whole_avg'] = round( $this->data[$ID]['dec_avg'] );


    file_put_contents($this->data_file, serialize($this->data));
    $this->get_ratings();
}
} //ends if isset
# ---
# end class
}

?>
```

The part that should check if the cookie exist is this:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE[$id])) {
```

but for some reason nothing in the script works when i add that.

Comment: I didn't go through all your code, but you have a mix of $id and $ID which could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE[$id])) {
```

You declared everything as `$ID`, but you're using `$id`. Try switching that out and see if it works.

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE[$ID])) {
```

Comment: Whoops, looks like somebody else answered that in the comments. He gets credit. But it does look like this is your problem so I'll leave this up.

Answer (score 0):

i think what you wanted to do is  isset (if exist) intead of !isset (if doesn t exist)

```
if (isset($_COOKIE[$id])) {
```

Comment: it should only run the script if the cookie doesn't exist so nothing wrong there